# Why is my data type converted back from big endian to little endian when I assign them?

Tags: c#, endianness

I have a problem considering the endianness of my data types. I have to send data over the ethernet using TCP / IP. The byte order however needs to be big endian when being sent and is in big endian, when being received. Therefore I try to reverse all my date before sending it using this class:

```
class ReverseBinaryReader : BinaryReader
{
    private byte[] a16 = new byte[2];
    private byte[] ua16 = new byte[2];
    private byte[] a32 = new byte[4];
    private byte[] a64 = new byte[8];
    private byte[] reverse8 = new byte[8];
    public ReverseBinaryReader(System.IO.Stream stream) : base(stream) { }

    public override int ReadInt32()
    {
        a32 = base.ReadBytes(4);
        Array.Reverse(a32);
        return BitConverter.ToInt32(a32, 0);
    }

    public override Int16 ReadInt16()
    {
        a16 = base.ReadBytes(2);
        Array.Reverse(a16);
        return BitConverter.ToInt16(a16, 0);
    }

    [ . . . ] // All other types are converted accordingly.

}
```

This works fine till I assign the converted values like this:

```
ReverseBinaryReader binReader = new ReverseBinaryReader(new MemoryStream(content));

this.Size = binReader.ReadInt16();  // public short Size
```

For example, if I want to save the bytes: 0x00, 0x02 as big endian, I would expect this in the memory: 0x0200 however the short value of Size would become 0x0002. Why is that?

Any ideas? Thanks,
Peer

// Edit 2:

To clear the issue up a little I'll try to show an example:

```
public class Message {
    public short Size;
    public byte[] Content;

    public Message(byte[] rawData)
    {
        ReverseBinaryReader binReader = new ReverseBinaryReader(new MemoryStream(rawData));

        this.Size = binReader.ReadInt16();  // public short Size
        this.Content = binReader.ReadBytes(2); // These are not converted an work just fine.
    }
}

public class prog {
     public static int main()
     {
          TCPClient aClient = new TCPClient("127.0.0.1",999); // Async socket
          aClient.Send(new Message(new byte[] { 0x00, 0x02 } );
     }
}
```

Comment: It's very unclear whether the problem is with what data is being sent, or how it's being received. Please show a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: I tried to clear it up a little, did it help? :P

Comment: Not a lot - there's still no short but complete program demonstrating the problem...

Comment: Using your aMsg example, what values does `a16` have and what value is returned by `return BitConverter.ToInt16(a16, 0);`

Comment: a16 has the values: 0x02, 0x00 which is correct. The return value is 2 (0x0002)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:**

Moved this to the top, since it is the actual answer.

I had to stare at it for far to long, but here is the source of your error.

- Your initial array is { 0x00, 0x02 } In LE that is 0x0200, BE is 0x0002
- You send it across the network, and read the first two bytes still { 0x00, 0x02 }
- You reverse it giving you {0x02, 0x00} LE is 0x0002, BE is 0x0200
- Your architecture is Little Endian so you get the "correct" result of 0x0002.

Ergo the error is in your test array. You can verify that your Architecure is little endian by checking the IsLittleEndian property on BitConverter.

```
=====================================================
```

The following code is to help clarify, more than it is to answer your direct question. And to show that BitConverter is predictable on all architectures.

```
using System;

namespace BitConverterTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            UInt32 u32 = 0x01020304;

            byte[] u32ArrayLittle = {0x04, 0x03, 0x02, 0x01};
            byte[] u32ArrayBig = {0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04};

            if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
            {
                if (BitConverter.ToUInt32(u32ArrayLittle, 0) != u32)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Failed to convert the Little endian bytes");
                }
                Array.Reverse(u32ArrayBig); // convert the bytes to LittleEndian since that is our architecture.
                if (BitConverter.ToUInt32(u32ArrayBig, 0) != u32)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Failed to convert the Big endian bytes");
                }
            } else
            {
                Array.Reverse(u32ArrayLittle); // we are on a big endian platform
                if (BitConverter.ToUInt32(u32ArrayLittle, 0) != u32)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Failed to convert the Little endian bytes");
                }
                if (BitConverter.ToUInt32(u32ArrayBig, 0) != u32)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Failed to convert the Big endian bytes");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're right about that. As embarrassing it may be for me, I have to admit, that I mixed up the endianness and the byte order and therefore became completely confused.
Thanks for clearing that up!

Comment: Don't feel bad it is easy to get confused when you are mentally switching back and forth between one endianess and another. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following:

```
public override Int16 ReadInt16()
{
    a16 = base.ReadBytes(2);
    return ((Int16)a16[1] * 0x00FF) + (Int16)a16[0];
}

public override int ReadInt32()
{
    a32 = base.ReadBytes(4);
    return ((int)a32[3] * 0x00FFFFFF) + (int)a32[2] * 0x0000FFFF) + (int)a32[1] * 0x000000FF) + (int)a32[0];
}
```

As for why this works, if you expect 0x00, 0x02 to be 0x0200 then you are using little-endian (since the least significant byte is first).

Since BitConverter is system depenate and your implementation is not, I would suggest trying to stay way from it where reasonable.

Comment: Yes, this did the trick! Thank you very much! I still wonder why the BitConverter did not work, but as long as this works, its ok with me.

Comment: @peer I added a possible explanation to the issue.  Since you are accessing the array directly I have taken out the Array.Reverse line and swapped the indexes.  I have also added a 32bit example which might help.

Comment: Bitconverter is predictable. It can even tell you the endianess of the architecture with the IsLittleEndian property. It does the same operation on all systems, you just have to put the bytes in the correct order for your architecture **before** you call it. Technically you can do it afterwards, but it is far easier to do it before.

Comment: @Trisped: For BitConverter or equivalent class to work you have to understand the endianess of the incoming data as well as the endianess of the architecture your program is currently running on.You have to check BitConverter.IsLittleEndian (or its equivalent) to make sure you are handling endianess correctly. So it is unreasonable to tell him to avoid BitConverter as it is no more and no less system dependent than any other solution. If he were to use his code, as is, on a big endian platform it would break since he would be unnecessarily swapping the bytes.

Comment: @grieve Since we are commenting on my post I will refer to the code in my answer.  The OP states "_The byte order however needs to be big endian when being sent and is in big endian, when being received._"  Since the communication stream must always be in big-endian, you could use the code in my example on a big or little endian platform without issue.  As you point out, he could just check the IsLittleEndian property and if true swap the order before using BitConverter.  This does not make sense to me in the situation he described.

Comment: @Trisped Because the data is coming in as big endian, if you ran your code on a big endian platform it would break, since you are reversing the bytes when you don't need to. If the incoming endianess and architecture endianess are identical there is no need to swap/reverse the bytes. Your code always reverses the bytes regardless of system endianess.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17579/discussion-between-grieve-and-trisped)

Comment: @grieve says no one is in chat (they really need to work on that interface).  I agree, my code is not big-endian, but it gets what he is looking for.  If it is wrong it is always wrong and easily fixed.  At this point the question is "_Are his expectations wrong or are his requirements?_"  I will be in chat for ~2 hours